# Ethernet.pm module throwing DDD in output

Tags: linux, perl, debugging, scripting, output

Its weird to explain but, we have perl script in cron and it working working great but some how today it started throwing output with `DDD` in from of all line.

what is `DDD` in perl script output? something like this? where this DDD coming from? we don't have any debug enabled.

```
 DDD inspecting interface ...
 DDD   but it is not active.
 DDD inspecting interface ...
 DDD   but it is not active.
 DDD inspecting interface ...
 DDD   but it is not active.
 DDD inspecting interface ...
 DDD   it is active...
 DDD   but it's the loopback.
 DDD inspecting interface ...
```

Comment: It looks like the Perl debugger, "DDD".  SUGGESTION: check your cron job and your .pl Perl script to see if either of them is somehow invoking the debugger, for example `perl -d ...`: https://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/

Comment: i have checked every piece, cron, script etc.. nothing found. if i copy same script in other system it works fine. but on this system it is throwing `DDD` is there any perl env variable or hidden debug option which causing debug?

Comment: @paulsm4, DDD is not the Perl debugger. DDD is a GUI front end for multiple debuggers, including the perl debugger.

Comment: @ikegami - Don't split hairs.  Neither Satish or I can think of any reason for "DDD" in the output, but it's worth noting that there *is* a debugger for Perl named "DDD", and *perhaps* something in the script or environment happened to be invoking it.

Comment: @Satish - no, I don't know of any environment variables that might the culprit :(  ADDITIONAL SUGGESTIONS: 1) Do you see "DDD" in the output for any of your *own* scripts?  2)  Does the problem appear/disappear if you run "cron" vs "command line"? 3) Can you running the offending script with a different version of Perl, and do you get the same behavior?  4) Can you step into the script with the Perl debugger to identify the culprit?  Please let us know what you find!

Comment: @paulsm4, I'm not splitting hair. It means this might not be coming from the Perl debugger. It also means that if it is coming from the Perl debugger, it's because it was instructed to do so from an external source (which points to env var).

Comment: in forum we should use negative voting comment section. so people know why they gave negative.. its so weird this question mark negative. I would prefer delete this question instead of negative vote

Answer (score 2):

To answer "what is DDD in perl script output? something like this? where this DDD coming from? we don't have any debug enabled."

DDD as said in the comments happens to be a debugger, but this isn't what's happening in yours. You're using ethernet.pm which has various debug output:

```
foreach my $rh (@a)
    {
    my $sName = $rh->{sAdapter};
    _debug(" DDD inspecting interface $sName...\n");
    if (! $rh->{iActive})
      {
      _debug(" DDD   but it is not active.\n");
      next TRY_ADDR;
      } # if
    _debug(" DDD   it is active...\n");
```

And so on. Looking at that module it has:

```
use vars qw( $DEBUG $VERSION @EXPORT_OK %EXPORT_TAGS );
$DEBUG = 0 || $ENV{N_A_E_DEBUG};
```

So debug is getting set to true, this isn't a Perl specific output, it happens to be the output of that module. So this hopefully answers where it's coming from and why you're seeing it.

As for why this has only just happened, something changed... What updates have you done, what changes to crontab etc That's the easiest way rather than for us to speculate at possible reasons, as you've said there's no environment variables set for the user running it, including no crontab env options. Go back through any recent system changes or updates.

Comment: Oh!! I think you are on right track.. But suddenly why it just started? I will check system if anybody updated anything but I doubt.

Comment: Look like `perl-Net-Address-Ethernet-1.122-1` package updated on system and it started this issue. How can we stop that `DDD` stuff..

Comment: I don't know what changed as I don't know what you were using before. What OS are you running as you may be using cronie. But a test would be to set N_A_E_DEBUG to 0. 

There's no point doing this on your terminal as you say it works anyway when you run it manually. So what OS are you running and how are you running it? Do you just have a link to the script in /etc/cron.X or is it in crontab? You could export it via crontab but need to know how you're running it.

Comment: sorry but it was throwing error when running manually on shell. look at this https://rtcpan.develooper.com/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=82843  they are having same issue.  i have tried `export N_A_E_DEBUG=0` also but no luck

Comment: That's not the same issue you're having. When they ran it on FreeBSD the usage is spat out for arp due to an incorrect argument.